# CakePHP need to know model ID before saving

Tags: cakephp, save

My situation:
I have a form based on several models linked together.
In background I have a routine for saving images , based on ajax call to a particular controller which uploads the image and displays it on a textarea in realtime.
My problem applies when I have to save the record first time, because the ajax routine needs to know the ID of the record to associate the image , but this will be created only after save() will be called.
Is there a way to obtain a ID before the model saves? or some other workaround

Thanks in advance to everyone

Rudy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @RichardAtHome provides a good input on this. I'll just add a third solution you may want to consider:

Use universally unique identifiers ([UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) for that model's primary key. CakePHP offers a way to generate them via the [`String`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html) utility. So what you would do is generate the id when the page loads with `String::uuid()` and then send it as part of the ajax requests.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion: I have used this approach and now all works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: Extra idea: check if the id exists in your database table when using `String::uuid()`. I think the chances of getting a non unique id is very, very small, but it is still a chance. And when programming, I don't believe in "chances", I want to have 100% control of what is happening. So that might be something to think about when using this approach :)

Comment: @jelmer UUIDs have 122 bits of entropy so the chance of two random UUIDs colliding is about 10^-37, I will take my chances - or buy a lottery ticket

Answer (score 2):

A couple of solutions:

1. Change your workflow, so that the images can only be linked to the main model once the main model has been saved (and has an id).
2. Don't save your images to the database until the main model has been created. You could store them in a session, or just keep appending fields to the end of the form as the user adds more fields.

Answer (score 2):

**Option1:**

You could try using UUIDs instead of INTs.  That way, you can just use CakePHP to generate an ID:  `String::uuid();`.

After you create it, you can populate an id field that would then make the item save with that id.

I'm not sure I'd rely on it's uniqueness if I were doing banking software or something critical, but - it's something like 1 in a billion chance to be duplicate, and for normal websites/software, it seems like that would suffice.

**Option2:**

In a lot of our projects, we've found it helpful to have a very simple "create a Thing" page with just a title field, then, once saved, it takes them immediately to the more in-depth "edit" page where they can upload files, save extra data...etc etc.  Almost like a pg1, pg2.  That way, files, as well as any other dynamic ajax-driven data will have an ID to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, because the ID will be set by the Database, and not CakePhp, and the id can only be known after the database has auto-incremented the ID field...

Not sure how your flow is, but I guess you can save a dummy/empty row to the database without all the associations when the controller gets the page (when $this->data is empty). You know have an ID to an empty row in the database that is like "12, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ...". You can then store the ID of that dummy record (or do $this->set("id", $id) to pass it to the view to use in your ajax-calls). 
After the POST of your page you can then use the ID to store all other information in dummy row, or delete the dummy row from the database when something fails/user navigates away...